# Create cache table

Tags: sql-server, query, table, cache

I need help with SQL Server. There is a task scheduled to run an .exe file. After the exe finish execution, I can get the logs below:

```
2021-03-05 22:45:00 : Create cache table 
2021-03-05 22:45:00 : Read computer data from database 
2021-03-05 22:49:35 : Cache computer data done 
2021-03-05 22:49:38 : Drop cache table
```

On a server there is a path \domain\rlc$. Under this path, there are 2 folders "In" and 'Out'. You go on 'In' folder and create there a file with .list extension(into this file you should enter one info/row, like in the picture[image].)
After that you go into the 'Out' folder and there is generated a csv file with the information provided in 'In' and several more columns.
When I made a test and create a test.list I saw in Task Manager a process that access the TLC.exe file. I thinking that in .exe file is the query that build the csv. Now I need the output to be different. Add some more columns to csv.

My question is: How can I see what information are into that table? What columns? Is there any solution to change the columns in that table? Add some, remove some!
After all processes are executed, I get a csv file with 10 columns. What I want to do is to identify the query behind, to remove one column and add a new one.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to find out. The name of the table. I think the query is inside the .exe file. TLC.exe is the name of the file. I will edit the question!

Comment: I don't have access to the code. Just see the .exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the SQL Server that the table lives on, you can connect via [**SQL Server Management Studio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) and run the [**Profiler**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) right before and during the process TLC.exe runs and generates the CSV file to capture the query that is ran.

Additionally in **SSMS** you can either run a [**Trace**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-ver15) or [**Extended Events Session**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) during the TLC.exe process to capture the SQL query as well, as Stephen mentions.

Any one of those three options should help you, just depends which one you find easiest and you have access too. I personally think the **Profiler** is the simplest for ad-hoc tracing.